# Where do i put the try-catch in my for-loop?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, try-catch

I'm now done with the basics of my code, and it works like it should. But now i want to add a try-catch exception so that if the user put is anything else than integers, it will throw an exception and say something like: Wrong input try again. Here is where i need it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nummer.Length; i++)
                {

                    Console.Write("Nummer " + talnr + ": ");
                    talnr++;
                    string str = Console.ReadLine();
                    int element = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                    nummer[i] = element;

                }
```

The loop will loop 10 times and store the inputs in an array. When i try it either makes an exception but contiues the loop or breaks the loop and goes on to the next block of code..

Comment: That depends on where you want to continue executing after you `catch`.

Comment: Write a method that gets *one* string from the user, until they provide one that is valid.  Once you have that method, writing the code to go around it to do the rest becomes much easier.

Comment: @SLaks Well, the user will be asked to enter 10 numbers. If the first number is anything but integers , i dont want it to continue the loop, but ask the user to try again until correct inputs are made. Same is if the user enters letters after 5 loops!

Comment: Please remember to mark one of the responses as the accepted answer so anyone else who visits the thread can see which answer supplied the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would favour the use of...

```
bool parsed = Int.TryParse(str, out myInt);
If (parsed)
{
    // do something
}
```

IMHO, a try/catch block should only really be used when there is a possibility on an unhandled exception (e.g. something volatile such as filesystem interaction) that cannot be "predicted" so as to handle accordingly (e.g. log errors etc.) and then continue without crashing your program.

Always try and handle a "known" with the methods and functions available in the framework to do so.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do doesn't require a `try-catch`. You can use the `TryParse` method to check whether the desired input is a properly formed integer, and prompt the user to enter a different input.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nummer.Length; i++)
{
    bool isAnInteger = false;
    int element = 0;

    Console.Write("Nummer " + talnr + ": ");
    talnr++;
    string str = Console.ReadLine();

    // evaluates to true if str can be parsed as an int, false otherwise
    // and outputs the parsed int to element
    isAnInteger = int.TryParse(str, out element); 

    while (!isAnInteger)
    {
        Console.Write("Wrong input, try again. ");
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        isAnInteger = int.TryParse(str, out element);
    }


    nummer[i] = element;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasnt sure ´try-catch´ was the way to go. I'm very new and still learning! 
Amazing how quickly you get respones on this site!!

Comment: @Simon: I'm assuming that everyone is taught to use `Convert.ToInt32` (or `int.Parse`).  It seems every beginner uses that to parse input.  You should quickly learn that using _SomeTypeGoesHere_.`TryParse` is always better (if it's available).  Exceptions should be for _exceptional_ situations; bad user input is anything but exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

Use the int.TryParse method.

This code reads the trimmed input string from the user and tries to convert it to an integer.  If the conversion is successful, it creates an integer variable called "result" which you can then use in the IF block.  If the conversion fails, you can write the code for what you want to happen in the ELSE block.  If you need a total of 10 integers in the list, I would drop the FOR loop in favor of a DO WHILE loop that checks for how many integers were successfully converted and added to the list.  It will keep requesting input until the list is filled with 10 integers.

```
List<int> elements = new List<int>();

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer.");

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().Trim(), out int result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You entered the integer {result}");
        elements.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter an integer. Please try again.");
    }

} while (elements.Count < 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a good idea to not throw exceptions at all if you can help it. In this case, you can use `int.TryParse()` instead. This block of code can replace your one `int element...` line:

```
int element;
if (!int.TryParse(str, out element)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Bad!!");
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

The `i--` is to make sure that `i` has the same value on the next interaction of the loop. Doing that will make sure you still get 10 valid inputs before you finish the loop. (Many will say this is a really bad thing to do, but the reason for that is readability - if you have a large `for` loop and decrement the value somewhere in the middle, it makes it difficult for the next guy looking at your code to understand exactly what's going on. But this is a short loop, so it's pretty obvious. Just be aware of this.)

The `continue` keyword skips the rest of that iteration of the loop and moves on to the next (so you don't add the bad value to your array).

Comment: `i--` in a `for(int i = ...)` loop is in general a very bad idea.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. :) For a short loop like this it doesn't harm readability.

Comment: Code quality is not just opinion or taste.

Comment: Whilst I don't agree with Henk that in general it is a bad idea to use the decrement operator and that this may be subject to opinion, I've been a professional developer for a good number of years now and have never found a legitimate requirement for its use. Just because you can, doesn't mean that you should!

Comment: I agree I would probably write this differently myself. But it's short enough that it really makes no difference either way. It's not a 200-line for loop with a `i--` hidden in the middle. It's pretty obvious what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep your code with the try catch loop here it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nummer.Length; i++)
        {
            try { 

            Console.Write("Nummer " + talnr + ": ");
            talnr++;
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int element = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            nummer[i] = element;

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, numbers only");
                goto breakloop;
            }

        }
        breakloop:;
```

The goto statement ends the loop if an error occured

Comment: I strongly advise against the use of goto statements. In the case of the example above, this serves no purpose as the natural logical flow outside of the try catch reaches the same conclusion. Goto statements are a relic of a time since passed, have likely been included in the .NET framework for compatibility/legacy purposes and I would always advocate the use of proper logical flow statements over goto statements. When you've got a minute, Google "why are goto statements bad" to see why!